# How to configure a maven based java module project to run unit test in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, module

I set up a "Maven Project" (simple project) in eclipse and added a class and unit tests for it. The tests are running fine.

However, as soon as I add a "module-info.java" to "src/main/java" the unit test failed to launch:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class workspace2.unittest.target.test-classes
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: workspace2.unittest.target.test-classes
```

Info: "workspace2" is the name of my workspace and "unittest" the project name.

It's running fine if I run maven via console (same maven and java version).

Set up:
- eclipse: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
- maven: 3.6.0 (configured in eclipse)
- java: oracle-jdk-9.0.4 / openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64

Has anybody else had this kind of issues?

I tried it with JUnit4 (4.12 and 4.13-beta-1) and JUnit5 (5.3.2).

**UPDATE**
Here a link to a zipped example project: https://www.file-upload.net/download-13475608/unittest.zip.html

**pom:**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.test</groupId>
<artifactId>unittest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**module-info.java:**

```
module de.unittest {
}
```

**class:**

```
package unittest;

public class Demo {

  public int calculate(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
  }
}
```

**test:**

```
package unittest;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DemoTest {

  private Demo demo;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    demo = new Demo();
  }

  @Test
  public void testCalculate() throws Exception {
    int calculated = demo.calculate(1, 2);
    assertEquals(3, calculated);
  }
```

}

Comment: Please show the code and the pom files...or may be link to a Github project?

Comment: I just uploaded a zip containing the project:
https://www.file-upload.net/download-13475608/unittest.zip.html

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to be bombed with Ad's...etc. ..

Comment: ad blocker a quite usefull... anyway I just added the code and pom

Comment: Works for me without a problem, but I think you should not use <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source> with JDK 9.

Comment: That was also my thought. I replaced the JDK with "openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin".  |  
  
maven: "Java version: 11.0.2" --> tests successfull  |  
eclipse: JavaSE-11 (jdk-11.0.2) --> same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. The error was caused by a white space inside the workspace path. :/ After creating a new workspace (without white space inside the path) the tests are running fine.

Comment: I seems that the white space breaks the run configuration's command line.
I just reported an bug to eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543851